# Syntax error compiling in Clojure leiningen

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have a project named `cheshire-cat` in which I am trying to run Rhino-based ClojureScript REPL with the command `lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-rhino`. It gives an exception in thread "main" and terminates.
What is the problem? Following is the terminal output:

```
$lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-rhino  
Running Rhino-based ClojureScript REPL.
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling at (cljs/repl.clj:1:1).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7647)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6824.invoke(core.clj:6126)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6765.invoke(core.clj:5948)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5985)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5969)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at cljsbuild.repl.rhino$eval144$loading__6706__auto____145.invoke(rhino.clj:1)
    at cljsbuild.repl.rhino$eval144.invokeStatic(rhino.clj:1)
    at cljsbuild.repl.rhino$eval144.invoke(rhino.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:463)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:428)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6824.invoke(core.clj:6126)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6125)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6109)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5908)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5903)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6765.invoke(core.clj:5948)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5947)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5985)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5969)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6007)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init5565266544074168037.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init5565266544074168037.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:77)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2207)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(RT.java:2220)
    at cljs.repl$eval150$loading__6706__auto____151.invoke(repl.clj:9)
    at cljs.repl$eval150.invokeStatic(repl.clj:9)
    at cljs.repl$eval150.invoke(repl.clj:9)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    ... 67 more
```

This is my `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject cheshire-cat "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371"]] 
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.6"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.8"]]
  :ring {:handler cheshire-cat.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.2"]]}}
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{
        :source-paths ["src-cljs"]
        :compiler {
          :output-to "resources/public/main.js"
          :optimizations :whitespace
          :pretty-print true}}]})
```

I tried to change the dependencies version to make it work but it didn't.
How to remove this error and make the command run the REPL without any error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with using newer JDKs (9+) with older software that used some packages only available until JDK8. You can fix this by adding

```
[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.1"]
```

to your `:dependencies` in `project.clj`.

Comment: It is giving another error: https://pastebin.com/HXUQip7f

Comment: What is this `project.clj` you are starting with? The ClojureScript version `"0.0-2371"` is something like 10 years old. Also many of the other versions are severly outdated? You should really consider starting with a more modern starting point? The Rhino REPL is also very likely to not work anymore? Maybe consider more modern things like shadow-cljs or figwheel-main?

Comment: I am reading "Living Clojure" book and in it, the author says to stick with ClojureScript version ```"0.0-2371"``` to follow up the demo. Still, I tried the latest version ```"1.11.60"``` and it ended up with error - https://pastebin.com/5NPwAAR1. How to make Rhino REPL work?

Comment: Unfortunately that book seems to be rather outdated. The Rhino REPL had been deprecated for many years, and removed entirely a while ago.  So, if you must use it stick with the really old version. The other error you were seeing is probably due to a newer Clojure Version, maybe downgrade `org.clojure/clojure` to the version used in the book?

Comment: It worked. But now I'm getting another error: on executing command ```lein cljsbuild auto``` in another terminal window, it gives ```java.lang.IllegalAccessException``` error. See pastebin: https://pastebin.com/yQc8rgNr

Comment: That again is a JDK issue. If you must follow such outdated examples downgrade your Java version on your System to Java/JDK 8. Then you can follow the book without any adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about dependencies, it's about the JDK version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/564509

And there's already an issue for that: https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/issues/499

Comment: How to resolve this issue? Can you tell me about the changes to be made?